# Byte array as String representation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with my byte array. Instead of converting to a string, it's just giving question marks and I think there might be something wrong with the first byte `b(0)`. Any chance someone could have a look at my code for me? Thanks.

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Const R As Integer = 6
    Dim e() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    e = GetBytes
    For i = 1 To UBound(e) Step 2
        e(i) = Abs(e(i) - (i / 2 + 1) - R)
    Next

    MsgBox e

End Sub
Private Function GetBytes() As Variant
    Dim b(197) As Byte

    b(0) = 77: b(2) = 109: b(4) = 123: b(6) = 124: b(8) = 132: b(10) = 44
    b(12) = 80: b(14) = 118: b(16) = 129: b(18) = 121: b(20) = 132: b(22) = 134
    b(24) = 128: b(26) = 117: b(28) = 136: b(30) = 54: b(32) = 139: b(34) = 135
    b(36) = 57: b(38) = 123: b(40) = 135: b(42) = 136: b(44) = 61: b(46) = 127
    b(48) = 147: b(50) = 64: b(52) = 116: b(54) = 150: b(56) = 132: b(58) = 135
    b(60) = 144: b(62) = 149: b(64) = 157: b(66) = 141: b(68) = 155: b(70) = 144
    b(72) = 151: b(74) = 155: b(76) = 164: b(78) = 92: b(80) = 60: b(82) = 58
    b(84) = 62: b(86) = 60: b(88) = 128: b(90) = 149: b(92) = 174: b(94) = 86
    b(96) = 176: b(98) = 167: b(100) = 174: b(102) = 90: b(104) = 161: b(106) = 165
    b(108) = 171: b(110) = 162: b(112) = 95: b(114) = 168: b(116) = 162: b(118) = 178
    b(120) = 179: b(122) = 173: b(124) = 179: b(126) = 171: b(128) = 186: b(130) = 187
    b(132) = 105: b(134) = 179: b(136) = 185: b(138) = 108: b(140) = 127: b(142) = 126
    b(144) = 128: b(146) = 134: b(148) = 94: b(150) = 92: b(152) = 123: b(154) = 181
    b(156) = 204: b(158) = 183: b(160) = 208: b(162) = 120: b(164) = 191: b(166) = 204
    b(168) = 202: b(170) = 201: b(172) = 125: b(174) = 191: b(176) = 127: b(178) = 203
    b(180) = 198: b(182) = 219: b(184) = 197: b(186) = 211: b(188) = 198: b(190) = 216
    b(192) = 203: b(194) = 137: b(196) = 146

    GetBytes = b
End Function
```

Comment: `For i = 1 To UBound(e) Step 2` should be `For i = 0 To UBound(e) Step 2` and the first byte should be 84 rather than 77 ;) Nice message though.

Comment: Ouah. Touching cryptography (y)

Comment: Ah @Rory, I was beginning to wonder if anyone would get it! Just found out about this double byte array for strings, so thought I'd give it a go with a bit of fun. Am in NZ so Xmas days starts soon. Have a good one.

Comment: @Rory Totally missed it :-)  Added a spoiler to my answer and corrected the first character as Rory suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to display a byte but it's actually an array of bytes.

**Option 1**

Change the type from `Byte` to `Variant` and use Join.  You must change `e` and `b` variables to `Variant` data type for `Join` to work.  The advantage is that you avoid a loop and is simple to follow.

```
MsgBox Join(e, "")
```

---

**Option 2**

Loop through array and display each value.

```
Dim itm As Variant
For Each itm In e
    Debug.Print itm
Next itm
```

---

**Bonus**

You can also output the array to cells.

```
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set Destination = Destination.Resize(1, UBound(e))
Destination.Value = e
```

[image]

---

**Results when outputting the Ascii character** (Mouse over to reveal spoiler)

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for full response. Agree with everything you say; only thing I'd add is that I've only just discovered that strings are stored as byte arrays where each character is two bytes large, byte(0) is ascii value and byte(1) is zero. Each byte can be manipulated individually and, what really surprised me, outputting it as a string requires no loop, hence `MsgBox e` works fine. Thanks again for your answer.